# Can't update Oracle IOT table with jbdc updateRow method

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have Oracle 10gR2 database with IOT table within:

```
create table countries (
 id number primary key, 
 name varchar2(30) not null enable
) organization index;
```

I try to update table values with this Java (version 1.6) code:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
                  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

ResultSet src = stmt.executeQuery("select id, name from countries");

src.next();

src.updateString("name", "__test__");
src.updateRow();
```

But updateRow throws SQLException (ORA-01410: invalid ROWID). If I try to update a heap (ordinary) table - all works.

I have use this code with different versions of oracle drivers (from here http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_10201.html)

After some research I have detected that IOT and HEAP table have different format of rowids:

IOT example  *BAJzKgwCwRb+

HEAP example AAAbgVAAJAAMyr8AAA

But I still don't know how to solve this problem. Are you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the results of an extended SQL trace of your query to see what JDBC's doing under the covers?  I suspect it's attempting to do

`UPDATE COUNTRIES SET NAME = '__TEST__' WHERE ROWID = :rowid_fetched`

and ROWID means something totally different in Oracle IOT's; it's not the immutable address of a row, but a guess as to the path to the row.

My recommendation as to how to do this is to propagate a system-generated timestamp field onto all of your tables, and use that for concurrency control rather than declaring an updatable recordset -- which will take and hold locks for every record in the recordset.

Then your application would fetch the rowset as normal, but issue statements like:

`UPDATE COUNTRIES SET NAME = '__TEST__' WHERE MOD_TS = :mod_ts_fetched`

to give stateless optimistic locking.

Comment: Trace is great idea! Thanks!

About your workaround idea: thanks but i don't need workaround, I want to understand why it is not work. Is it a bug or implementation restriction or just my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your table does not really need to be IOT. I would suggest you recreate it as a normal table and add index on both ID and name. Same performance, same logic, no ROWID problem.

Comment: Thank you for workaround but I want to understand why it is not work. Is it a bug or implementation restriction or just my mistake.

Comment: I haven't worked with Java but there probably is a setting that switches between "UPDATE BY ROWID" and "UPDATE BY PRIMARY KEY" or something like that.